# Firefox 21+ won't read video objects from mms protocol

Tags: html, firefox, video, mms

I have a website that delivers content from an `mms://` protocol, but latest Firefox version seem to ignore the video object. Is it possible to force Firefox to read/load files from an `mms://` protocol?

**HTML5**

```
<object classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" width="870" height="550" codebase="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/ object">
    <param name="Filename" value="mms://24.212.0.21/archives/tvc9/CC_A2013_01.wmv">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="true">
    <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
    <param name="BufferingTime" value="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
    <param name="AutoSize" value="true">
    <param name="InvokeURLs" value="true">
    <embed src="mms://24.212.0.21/archives/tvc9/CC_A2013_01.wmv" type="video/x-ms-wmv" autostart="true" bufferingtime="2" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="true" autosize="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,0,0,0" width="870" height="550">
</object>
```

It works in all other browsers. I cannot change the source server.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W55Jh/)

Comment: Even Microsoft seem to have dropped support for `mms://` transport in media services 2008, or are you talking about some new protocol I missed?

Comment: No it's nothing new. I can't seem to find a viable solution with the limitations set on the remote server, so I went for this protocol as I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Sorry, I know of no workaround, although since [Microsoft deprecated it in 2003](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Media_Server) in favour of RTSP, you may want to try that instead.

Comment: Looks like you're using a plugin here. Firefox has nothing to do with the request to `mms://`, the plugin will be doing it.  There is certainly no HTML5 going on.